# Pre-requisites for self-studying probability theory(Protter)

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I want to self-study basic **probability theory** in a rigorous way from the Springer book - [Probability essentials](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540438717) by Jean Jacod, Philip Protter. I have taken courses in

- **Calculus** : Worked through *Differential Calculus - N. Piskunov*.
- **Linear Algebra** : Worked through the first six chapters of *Linear Algebra done right - Sheldon Axler.*

I have no background in Analysis yet. I have only started reading Tao's book.

1. *What would be the pre-requisites for self-studying probability theory, and can these be picked up along the way?*
2. *Any recommendations for a great video lecture series that covers the subject material.*

P.S. I have done some leisure reading and problem solving of volume I of Feller.

Cheers!

Quasar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability theory depends heavily on measure theory. After you finish Tao's book, you may want to take a look at my new book *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis*, whose electronic version is legally available for free at
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-33143-6.pdf.
The last chapter of this book gives a brief introduction to measure-theory-based probability, but for an in-depth treatment of probability you should look elsewhere after learning measure theory.